# What is the significance of Christ being human?

Tags: john, jesus, christology, 1-john, body-of-christ

I appreciated the ideas shared on this platform around the 'water and the blood' from 1 John 5. The text I refer to is: 1 John 5:6.

> This is he who came by water and blood—Jesus Christ; not by the water
> only but by the water and the blood. And the Spirit is the one who
> testifies, because the Spirit is the truth.

I'm not looking for commentary on the text but rather asking why it is important that Jesus be human. My question: why is it really significant that Jesus was human in any case? Can someone explain that?

Comment: Can you expound a bit upon how 1 John 5:6 specifically relates to your question? It doesn't seem so direct.

Comment: Yes, this verse doesn't really seem to be about Jesus being human. If you want to know why it's important that Jesus is human, then you should probably ask that theological question on [christianity.se].

Comment: Another important Q closed with only traditional and Non-Biblical answers provided. The confused answers relying on an incarnation which no Biblical author taught. So much for Biblical Hermeneutics.

Comment: Jesus is the second and last Adam, Adam was a human who was required to depend on God, Jesus was  tasked with the same. Making Jesus God renders the whole mission farcical and contradicts the entire NT.

Answer (score 1):

**'Christ'** is an English title for the Greek "Χριστός" = ”Mashiach Ben David” מָשִׁיחַ בֶּן דָּוִד (Messiah Son [of] David) known also as The Ben(בְּנ):“Son” of יְהֹוָה, based on [Psalm 2:7].

**"Shafat" שָׁפַט = He-shall-Judge** as prophesied by יְשַֽׁעְיָהוּ בֶּן־אָמוֹץ Yeshayahu Ben-Amoz (Isaiah son of Amoz) in [Isaiah 2:4]. https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.2.4?with=Commentary&lang=bi

If Isaiah had claimed Christ was a female or Daughter of David in [Isaiah 2:4], then we would have read : שָׁפְטָה "Shaftah" instead of שָׁפַט "Shafat".

We learn also that the biological male human descendant of David will be the Mashiach in [Sukkah 52.a:6] :

> The Sages taught: To Messiah ben David, who is destined to be revealed swiftly in our time, the Holy One, Blessed be He, says: Ask of Me anything and I will give you whatever you wish, as it is stated: “I will tell of the decree; the Lord said unto me: You are My son, this day have I begotten you, ask of Me, and I will give the nations for your inheritance, and the ends of the earth for your possession” (Psalms 2:7–8).

Regarding the titles of the “Mashiach” from [Sukkah 52.a:6], Daf Shevui states :

> This midrash presents a dialogue between God and the Messiah, son of David, the Messiah that will usher in the end of days after the slaying of the Messiah son of Joseph. God tells this descendant of David that he can ask anything of him. But the Messiah wisely asks only for his life, which he is granted by God. - There may be some Christian overtones/polemics to this midrash, for according to this passage the real Messiah will not be slain.

Answer (score 0):

### A God who Sympathizes

> **[Matt 8:17](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=strong=G0769%7Cversion=ESV%7Cversion=SBLG&options=VHNGU&display=INTERLEAVED&qFilter=G0769)** (ESV) This was to fulfill what was spoken by the prophet Isaiah: “He took our illnesses`Grk:astheneia` and bore our diseases.”

The humanity of Christ is often underemphasized by Christians, says [Dr. Craig](https://www.reasonablefaith.org/podcasts/defenders-podcast-series-2/s2-doctrine-of-christ/doctrine-of-christ-part-1). The incarnation of Christ as a mortal man (born of a woman) distinguish him from the Greek or Hindu mythological gods, where the believers knew that those gods are fictional product of literary imaginations. The Greek gods hardly depicted as dying, since it doesn't serve any purpose if they would die like the mortals. They turn into something else after their death. The facts about the incarnation of God, in the Jewish religion as Son of God, sets it apart from the other religions. Nonetheless, there were some early pagan Christians, such as some [Gnostics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnosticism), who denied his true humanity, and put Christ back to the mythological status under their dualistic view, that God cannot become a man, and Christ only *appeared* as a man. The Roman doctrine of Christ's immunity from the alleged [original sin](http://www.ecclesia.org/truth/original_sin.html) is also in the same line of undermining his humanity. He wouldn't have been truly a substitutionary atonement for humans if he was not truly a human himself.

While the Jews knew well about God, and had the hope of resurrection, the incarnation reveals God in the fullest extent. This way, God broke all barriers of separation with man. Man does not have to consider God as an imaginary and out of reach. God cannot be accused of being unsympathetic and callous to human suffering, which is the greatest objection to theism. Thus, besides the point of the sacrificial atonement, (which is frequently preached without any practical & relatable reasons), his purpose is to demonstrate his power & love, and to come closer to man. To prove that he is not an imaginary god of the idols, stories & rituals.

These are the relevant passages showing that God sympathizes with us through his incarnation as a weak mortal man in every way, and that he does not hesitate to call us his brothers.

> **[Heb 2:9-18 ESV]**
> <sup>9</sup>But we see him who for a little while was made lower than the angels, namely Jesus, crowned with glory and honor because of the suffering of death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone. <sup>10</sup>For it was fitting that he, for whom and by whom all things exist, in bringing many sons to glory, should make the founder of their salvation perfect through suffering. <sup>11</sup>For he who sanctifies and those who are sanctified all have one source. That is why he is not ashamed to call them brothers, <sup>12</sup>saying, “I will tell of your name to my brothers; in the midst of the congregation I will sing your praise.” <sup>13</sup>And again, “I will put my trust in him.” And again, “Behold, I and the children God has given me.” <sup>14</sup>Since therefore the children share in flesh and blood, he himself likewise partook of the same things, that through death he might destroy the one who has the power of death, that is, the devil, <sup>15</sup>and deliver all those who through fear of death were subject to lifelong slavery. <sup>16</sup>For surely it is not angels that he helps, but he helps the offspring of Abraham. <sup>17</sup>Therefore he had to be made like his brothers in every respect, so that he might become a merciful and faithful high priest in the service of God, to make propitiation for the sins of the people. <sup>18</sup>For because he himself has suffered when tempted, he is able to help those who are being tempted.

> **[Heb 4:14-16 WEB]**
> <sup>14</sup>Having then a great high priest, who has passed through the heavens, Jesus, the Son of God, let us hold tightly to our confession. <sup>15</sup>For we don’t have a high priest who can’t be touched with the feeling of our infirmities`Grk:astheneia`, but one who has been in all points tempted like we are, yet without sin. <sup>16</sup>Let us therefore draw near with boldness to the throne of grace, that we may receive mercy, and may find grace for help in time of need.

[Word analysis](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g769/esv/tr/0-1/):  ἀσθένεια (astheneia) 'weakness' (G0769)
Meaning:

> weakness, illness, infirmity
> want of strength, weakness, feebleness 1Cor. 15:43; bodily infirmity, illness, state of ill health, sickness, Mt. 8:17; Lk. 5:15; metaphoically infirmity, frailty, imperfection, intellectual and moral, Rom. 6:19; 1Cor. 2:3; Heb. 5:2; 7:28; suffering, affliction, distress, calamity, Rom. 8:26

> LSJ dictionary
> ἀσθέν-εια, ἡ,
> want of strength, weakness, [Refs 5th c.BC+]; especially feebleness, sickliness, [Refs 5th c.BC+]
> __2 disease, sickness, [Refs 2nd c.BC+]; δι᾽ ἀσθένειαν[NT]
> __3 ἀ. βίου poverty, [Refs 5th c.BC+]
> __4 in moral sense, feebleness, weakness, τῆς ἀνθρωπίνης

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is meant to complement the existing answers, not to disagree with them.)

Consider how Jesus's incarnation is described in Philippians 2:5–11 (NKJV):

> **Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ Jesus**,
> who, being in the form of God, did not consider it robbery to be equal with God,
>
> but made Himself of no reputation, taking the form of a bondservant, and coming **in the likeness of men**.
> And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became **obedient to the point of death**, even the death of the cross.
>
> Therefore God also has highly exalted Him and given Him the name which is above every name,
> that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, of those in heaven, and of those on earth, and of those under the earth,
> and that every tongue should confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

Paul is saying that even though Jesus was physically human, he had a mind that was not like that of ordinary men
(his human spirit being combined with God's holy spirit), and that Christians should strive to develop their own minds to have that same strength and character that Jesus had.

In particular consider the NLT translation of verse 7 and 8:

> Instead, **he gave up his divine privileges**;
> he took the humble position of a slave
> **and was born as a human being**.
> When he appeared in human form,
> he humbled himself **in obedience to God**
> and died a criminal’s death on a cross.

We see that Jesus was truly incarnated as a fully human being, without any of the divine attributes he previously possessed.
It was while in this totally human form that Jesus resisted temptation and lived a sinless life in obedience to God's laws.

Just as the physical nation of Israel had been chosen to set an example to other nations of the physical benefits of obeying God,
and the spiritual nation of Israel (Christians) were chosen to set an example to other people of the spiritual benefits of obeying God,
Jesus chose himself to set a personal example demonstrating that it really *is* possible for an individual to live a sinless life (though not by oneself, but with the assistance of God's own spirit, which was received at baptism).

As Paul said elsewhere (1 Corinthians 10:13):

> The temptations in your life are no different from what others experience.
> And God is faithful.
> **He will not allow the temptation to be more than you can stand.**
> When you are tempted, he will show you a way out so that you can endure.

By temporarily surrendering his divinity and becoming a fully human being, Jesus provided the example that it is indeed possible for a human Christian to resist all temptation.

Answer (score 0):

two points that inform my view.

1. God made us in His Image and likeness and that must have been mentioned for some significance it had for all the rest of Salvation History.
2. As Pope Benedict said of Duns Scotus: Duns Soctus "unlike many Christian thinkers of the time, held that the Son of God would have been made man even if humanity had not sinned. He says in his "Reportatio Parisiensis":  "To think that God would have given up such a task had Adam not sinned would be quite unreasonable! I say, therefore, that the fall was not the cause of Christ's predestination and that if no one had fallen, neither the angel nor man in this hypothesis Christ would still have been predestined in the same way" (in III Sent., d. 7, 4). This perhaps somewhat surprising thought crystallized because, in the opinion of Duns Scotus the Incarnation of the Son of God, planned from all eternity by God the Father at the level of love is the fulfilment of creation and enables every creature, in Christ and through Christ, to be filled with grace and to praise and glorify God in eternity. Although Duns Scotus was aware that in fact, because of original sin, Christ redeemed us with his Passion, Death and Resurrection, he reaffirmed that the Incarnation is the greatest and most beautiful work of the entire history of salvation, that it is not conditioned by any contingent fact but is God's original idea of ultimately uniting with himself the whole of creation, in the Person and Flesh of the Son"

Answer (score 0):

This is really a theological issue, more than a hermeneutics question. But to stick to the text: 1 John is part of the so-called Johannine literature, traditionally ascribed to John the Apostle. The significance of Jesus being human is probably best understood with reference Gospel of John itself. This writing, more than any other NT scripture, develops Christology in a rather definite way. It is extremely important to this writer (whether he is the same person as the author of 1 John or someone writing in the same vein) that Christ is both man and God. He makes it clear that Christ is God in the very first verse:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
> was God.

A few verses later, the author introduces the crucial importance of Christ's humanity.

> The true light that enlightens every man was coming into the world.
> ...But to all who received him, who believed in his name, he
> gave power to become children of God;  who were born, not of blood
> nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of God. And
> the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, full of grace and truth; we
> have beheld his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father.

This sheds light on the verse in the OP. In the passage in the Gospel of John, Christians are reborn through the water of baptism and thereby "die" to their flesh. So their spiritual birth is not of blood

**In 1 John, Christ comes by water (referring to the baptism of John) *and* blood. As God, he must also be human and shed his blood on the Cross, in order to give eternal life to humanity.**

> Truly, truly, I say to you, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of man
> and drink his blood, you have no life in you; he who eats my flesh and
> drinks my blood has eternal life, and I will raise him up at the last
> day. For my flesh is food indeed, and my blood is drink indeed. (John
> 5:53-55)

By faith and participation in the sacraments of baptism and holy communion, John teaches, Christians come to partake in the divine nature as God's adopted children who possess eternal life. This idea was summarized by Athanasius of Alexandria, who said:

> "the Son of God became man so that we might become God."

A fuller treatment of this idea is developed this this article: [What “So that We Might Become God” Means](https://www.catholic.com/qa/what-so-that-we-might-become-god-means).

---

*As mentioned, this is a theological issue. One need not agree with the doctrine to understand why the author of 1 John and Christians throughout history have considered the idea as essential to their faith.*

Answer (score -1):

For Jesus to fulfill his redemptive mission, he must first assume a fleshly posture. We can find at least four reasons for this in scripture. Why does he have to become man?

•   Because divine form cannot die. As man, he will die.

•   Because the requirements of the Law of Moses required a sacrifice of flesh and blood. Divine form is not made of flesh and blood. (Hebrews 10)

•   Because his heritage must come from a specific fleshly lineage. As God, he has no lineage.

•   Because the demands of the Law were imposed upon man and it required that man fulfill them perfectly. Since the Law was given to a specific line of the seed of Abraham, it required that someone of that linkage must satisfy the demands of the Law, Romans 1:1-5.

So, fulfilling the function of a sacrifice required that Jesus assume the form of a sacrifice. By becoming flesh Jesus emptied out of himself his divine form. Divine essence is now submitted to limitations. As God the characteristics of essence are, by their very nature, without boundaries or limitations. As man, Jesus would be subjected to all the same sets of determined relations that limit all men. Divine character is now submitted to vulnerability. As God, he cannot be tempted, but as man, he would yield himself to the onslaught of Satan. He would become the second Adam. He exposed his own moral integrity to the same temptations that are common to all men, Hebrews 2:18, 4:15, and 5:2. Yet, unlike Adam, he maintained his integrity all the way to the cross as we will see later in chapter two. He succeeded where Adam failed. He simply never sinned.

Comment: *"Yet, unlike Adam, he maintained his integrity all the way to the cross **as we will see later in chapter two.** He succeeded where Adam failed. He simply never sinned."* ...Chapter two???

Comment: I cut and pasted this from my teaching outline on Hebrews. The chapter two refers to Hebrews 2.

Comment: @oldhermit, thanks for your response. You should give credit in the answer itself to your source and use some quotation indicator so it is clear which segments are your contribution and which are your source's.

Comment: Well, since the material is mine and is published in my name saw no reason to offer a source.

Comment: Ok gotcha. I missed that all-important word "my" reading quickly. Still it might be good to somehow indicate that it's a copy or quote from your website or otherwise adapt it so you don't indicate you're going to show your audience something in chapter 2 that you don't intend to show them in this medium.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.